# Use the LIKE operator with the value of a text field in APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I currently have this select statement

```
Select fullName
From mytable
Where fullName = :P32_Full_Name
```

:P32_Full_Name = the string that the user typed in the search box

I want to be able to use the LIKE operator using the :P32_Full_Name.

for example:

```
Select fullName
From mytable
Where fullName Like '%:P32_Full_Name%'
```

As you can see from the query above I am just trying to select from table the Full_Name that contains the
characters typed by the user. If I leave it without the Like operator as in the first query and the user
types 'Kimberly Clark' the query will not work because the table has 'Kimberly Clark Jr.'

Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're chasing

```
'%'||:P32_FULL_NAME||'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively: instead of `LIKE`, you could try with `INSTR`:

```
where instr(fullName, :P32_FULL_NAME) > 0
```